# IISExpress Development certificate is not installed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, deployment

I am creating a Web Application in Visual Studio 2012 Professional, I have recently Installed Windows Azure SDK 2.1. when i start the application by hitting **F5**. It Builds successfully but at the time of deployment, it show a pop up saying "**The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service**". In the Output window the Error is As follows:

**Windows Azure Tools: Error: IISExpress Development certificate is not installed.

Windows Azure Tools: Error: IISExpress Development certificate is not installed.

Windows Azure Tools: The system is missing a prerequisite to execute the service. Please see the release notes.**

Please Help me sorting this Issue, I installed the azure sdk from web platform installer 4.6 and i reinstalled it again, but the issue is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem recently but finally did find something that worked.

I followed the instructions from ***Install Instructions Step 8*** at [Download Windows Azure SDK for .NET - 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40893) , restarted VS, and it fixed my issues. Below are the instructions for Windows 7. Refer to the link for other versions of Windows.

> **OPTIONAL for full IIS** Enable IIS7 with ASP.NET and WCF HTTP Activation, Static Content, IIS Management Console, HTTP Redirection and optionally CGI, ISAPI Extensions, ISAPI Filters, Directory Browsing, HTTP Errors, Logging Tools, Request Monitor and Tracing, Request Filtering.
>
> - **Windows 7**
>
>   - From the Start menu, choose Control Panel | Programs | Programs and Features.
>   - Choose Turn Windows Features On or Off.
>   - Under Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, then Application  - Development Features, then select .NET Extensibility, ASP.NET, ISAPI Extensions and ISAPI Filters.
>   - Under Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, then Common HTTP Features, then select Directory Browsing, HTTP Errors, HTTP Redirection, Static Content.
>       Under Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, then Health and Diagnostics, then select Logging Tools, Request Monitor and Tracing.
>   - Under Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, then Security, then select Request Filtering.
>   - Under Internet Information Services, expand Web Management Tools, then select IIS Management Console.
>       Install the selected features.
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing IIS Express from Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features
find IIS XX.X Express right click and select repair.

XX.X represents a placeholder for the version number.